# How to insert an rvalue into map after calling a function on it

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, std

I'm trying to use a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<CObject>>` (hereby referred to as map) to be able to use the map for calling the same functions on different objects based on their name. Function pointers within the map would be one way to do it, but I thought it'd be cleaner to save the objects themselves in the map.

Now, the objects are stored in a `shared_ptr`, since they have dependencies from other usages (member functions automatically called before function calls, etc), and the `shared_ptr` are allocated using a function that wraps `make_shared`, which among other thing resets it, as well as catches and throws exceptions with added relevant information (probably not needed anymore, but it's a rather large code base, and it's a part of the coding standard). This function allocates the given objects by taking the `shared_ptr` as a reference, and returns void.

What I wanted to do was create a map with keys mapping to objects, and call the allocate function on all those objects. But since the allocate function does not return an OutputIterator or anything like it, I'm unable to use an `std::inserter`.

They way I don't want to do it is using lvalues, like:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<CObject>> objectMap;
shared_ptr< CObject> object;
allocate< CObject>( object );
objectMap.insert( make_pair("FirstObject", object ) );
```

The only way I've come up with is to call the allocate function on non-existing values on the map, as `map` would automatically create the objects for me if they don't exist. Like:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<CObject>> objectMap;
allocate< CObject>( objectMap["FirstObject"] );
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: _"But since the allocate function does not return an OutputIterator or anything like it, I'm unable to use an `std::inserter`."_ I failed to follow this bit - can you show what it was you hoped to do, but couldn't?  Is it acceptable to loop over the map twice, once to populate it with keys and again to populate the pointers? Where do the keys come from?

Comment: I've added more information now, hopefully it's a bit easier to understand what I wanted to do.

Comment: That's much clearer, thanks.  Your solution looks fine, but I've added another to my answer. My `transform` suggestion should be applicable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function object like this to create the map elements:

```
struct AllocCObject {
  std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<CObject>>
  operator()(const std::string& key) const
  {
    std::shared_ptr<CObject> p;
    allocate<CObject>(p);
    return { key, p };
  }
};

std::string keys[] =  { "k1", "k2", "k3" };
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<CObject>> map;
std::transform(std::begin(keys), std::end(keys), std::inserter(map), AllocCObject());
```

Or if you prefer to use a lambda instead of a function object:

```
auto allocObject = [] (std::string const& s) {
  std::shared_ptr<CObject> p;
  allocate<CObject>(p);
  return std::make_pair(s, p);
}
```

Alternatively, somewhat closer to your idea (which looks fine to me):

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<CObject>> map = {
  { "k1", {} }, { "k2", {} }, { "k3", {} }
};
for (auto& e : map)
  allocate<CObject>(e.second);
```

(N.B. I don't think VC++ supports initializing the map from an `initializer_list` like that, but it's valid C++11.)

Comment: The keys will be hard coded for each value in the map, and the map will probably only contain 5-6 values.

Comment: Thanks, I do like the transform solution, since that would let me create the vector and define the keys in one nice and concise place. It would be possible to do that via a lambda instead of a function object, right?
You are right on the VC++ issue of not supporting initializer_list, so sadly that's a no-go.

Comment: Yes, you could replace the functor with a lambda such as `[](std::string const& s) { std::shared_ptr<CObject> p; allocate<CObject>(p); return std::make_pair(s, p); }`

Comment: Thanks again! I added the lambda answer to the original answer!

Comment: Your edit got rejected for some reason, I guess the reviewers didn't read the comments, so I added it myself